# Toast message from Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service, toast

How do I make a Toast message from a thread when there is no running activity?

I started the app, made a new thread for background socket listening, and then exited app. However, the thread is then *still* listening for incoming socket request.

I started with this example: [BluetoothChat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat)
Somewhere in this place (BluetoothChatService.java line:243 from class "private class AcceptThread extends Thread") I start toast:

```
public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to pass a reference to an `Activity` when you initialize your class you can use `runOnUiThread()`. For example,

Global pointer...

```
Activity mActivity;
```

Your constructor...

```
public MyClass(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

A method inside `MyClass` to show a toast...

```
public void showToast(String message, int duration) {
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, message, duration);
        }
    }
}
```

And then just call that method whenever you would like.